# Running a maven jersey server from the command line

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm using [this link](https://chiaboy.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/simple-jersey-example-with-intellij-idea-and-tomcat/) as a jersey server for my application. Its a maven project. Can anyone tell me how do I run the server from the command line??

When I try this : `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.chiaboy.webapp.HelloWorldService"` it gives me an error saying

```
java.lang.Exception: The specified mainClass doesn't contain a main method with
appropriate signature.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss step #14: `Use tomcat7:run to run application on embedded version of tomcat`. Maven command would be `mvn tomcat7:run`.

Comment: Yes I figured that! Thanks!